# Update data sent to view from controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a map using Google Maps API that will show current position of players on a server. That list is updated by the game server and the data is stored in a MySql database that is hosted where the web application is. When a user opens the map the list of players and their positions is pulled from the database and sent to View

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(loadData()); //List<MapModel>
}
```

On the View I create a marker for each player at their respective locations. I have a timer that will create/update/delete the markers (I have removed the unnecessary code for this demonstration)

```
setInterval("updateMap();", 1000);
function updateMap()
{
    **<update data somehow>**
    @foreach(var player in Model)
    {
        <text>
        players[@player.playerid] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(@player.pos_x, @player.pos_y),
            map: map
        });
        </text>
    }
}
```

The question is how do I update the data?

Comment: You need to call the server and get the updated data.

Comment: The data is stored in a MySql database on the same server as the site. How do I call loadData() and get updated List<MapModel>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
 public JsonResult GetPlayers()
    {
        return Json(loadData()); //List<MapModel>
    }
```

and then in javascript using [jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method

```
 function updateMap()
    {

$.post('/SomeController/GetPlayers', function(data){

    for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++)
    {

        players[data[i].playerid] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(data[i].pos_x, data[i].pos_y),
            map: map
        });

    }
});

}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please note that this technique could be a bad practice if you have larger amount of players. You could use websockets to notify players about poistion changes. Please check ASP.NET [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) for that purpose.